# How does sys._getframe(1).f_lineno function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have found this test code and run it with various pieces of code and found it to be correct, but I am not able to understand how it written and what this line of code is doing and how it is doing it:

```
linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno
```

Can anyone please me tell me the working of the above line of code? The complete block of code is:

```
import sys

def test(did_pass):
    """  Print the result of a test.  """
    linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno   # Get the caller's line number.
    if did_pass:
        msg = "Test at line {0} ok.".format(linenum)
    else:
        msg = ("Test at line {0} FAILED.".format(linenum))
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows you line numbers of functions in a call stack.

E.g.,

```
import sys

def f1():
    f2()    # First call in the stack

def f2():
    f3()    # Second call in the stack

def f3():
    for num in range(3):
        frame = sys._getframe(num)
        show_frame(num, frame)  # Third call in the stack

def show_frame(num, frame):
    print(frame)
    print("  frame     = sys._getframe(%s)" % num)
    print("  function  = %s()" % frame.f_code.co_name)    # Shows the function/module name
    print("  file/line = %s:%s" % (frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno))   # Shows the stack line number it was called in

f1()
```

The output of the listing above looks like this:

```
<frame at 0x101172dc0, file 'temp.py', line 12, code f3>
  frame     = sys._getframe(0)
  function  = f3()
  file/line = temp.py:12
<frame at 0x101184200, file 'temp.py', line 7, code f2>
  frame     = sys._getframe(1)
  function  = f2()
  file/line = temp.py:7
<frame at 0x1011f29f0, file 'temp.py', line 4, code f1>
  frame     = sys._getframe(2)
  function  = f1()
  file/line = temp.py:4
```

Just check a corellation with the line numbers and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno

1. linenum is a variable created which will store the value of the line number required.
2. sys._getframe(1) will get the current function defined. (1)-current function.
3. f_lineno will fetch the value of the line number from the function(f).